Calculation of the projection w from Linear Discriminant Analysis
In an assigment focused on Linear Discriminant Analysis(LDA) there is this theoritical exercise:
A dataset has been derived from two classes $ \omega_A$ and $\omega_B$, the distributions of which are assumed to be Gaussian and the a priori probability of the first category is $P(\omega_A) = 0.4$. The covariance matrices and mean values have been estimated from the data as follows:
$$
\mu_A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}, \quad \mu_B = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\Sigma_A = \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}, \quad \Sigma_B = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Apply the LDA method analytically to compute the projection vector ( w ), performing the operations by hand. To invert the scattering matrix $ S_w $ (Within-Class Scatter Matrix), use the formula:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \frac{1}{ad - bc} \begin{bmatrix} d & -b \\ -c & a \end{bmatrix}
$$

My solution:
We begin by expressing the Fisher's criterion in terms of $S_w$ and $S_b$:
$$J(w)= \frac{w^{T}S_{B}w}{w^{T}S_{w}w}$$
To find the maximum of J(w) we differentate and equate to zero:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
        \frac{d}{dw}J(w) &= \frac{d}{dw} \left( \frac{w^{T}S_{B}w}{w^{T}S_{w}w} \right) = 0\\
&\Rightarrow (w^{T}S_{w}w)\frac{d}{dw}(w^{T}S_B w)- (w^{T}S_{w}w)\frac{d}{dw}(w^{T}S_B w)=0\\
&\Rightarrow (w^{T}S_{w}w)2S_Bw-(w^{T}S_{w}w)2S_Bw =0\\
\text{Dividing by $2w^{T}S_{w}w$: }\\
&\Rightarrow S_Bw-J(w)S_ww=0\\
&\Rightarrow S_B^{-1}S_Bw -J(w)w=0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
Now, solve the generalized eigen value problem
$$S^{-1}_wS_{B}w= \lambda w \text{ where } \lambda = J(w) = scalar $$
yields
$$ w{*} = argmaxJ(w) = argmax(\frac{w^{T}S_Bw}{w^{T}S_ww})= S_w^{-1}(\mu_{A}-\mu_{B})$$

So, based on the last equation we only need $S_w^{-1}(\mu_{A}-\mu_{B})$
Why the exercise give us the a-Priori possibility?
Should i use it to weight the besides scatter matrix?
Thanks in advance.
